What are some refutations to the etymological fallacy?
The "etymological fallacy" is the proposal that normatively defining a word in terms of its historical or etymological origins is "a fallacy". This claim seems incomplete, because it implies that, since words should not be normatively defined in terms of their etymology, they should be normatively defined in terms of something else.
Consider the following positions:

Words should be normatively defined in terms of their inherent denotational content.
Words should be normatively defined in terms of how they are being used.
Words should be normatively defined intentionally.
Words should not be normatively defined.

Each of these has issues, indicating that a more nuanced and precise theory is needed.

1 is the pro-etymology position, which aims to establish meaning communally and objectively, by considering meaning as systematically encoded in language. By decomposing the morphology of words, one can (hopefully) reduce them to a composed unit of semantic primitives. A counterargument here is that "semantic primitives" are arbitrary. If you defer the meaning of words to their semantic primitives, how do you determine the meaning of the semantic primitives?

2 is "hard descriptivism", which claims that words are fundamentally arbitrary, so there is no guiding rubric of "correct use" except how people are already using them. This would seem to be the position of people who hold the "argument from etymology" to be a fallacy, but it has its own contradictions: hard descriptivism is still normative, because it claims that we should recognize that a word has a certain meaning, and that meaning is the result of a census of usage. A possible paradox is that any word can mean anything if it is used that way.

3 is one of the most common strategies for the communal stabilization of meaning, the "mixed methods" of intentional definition. Someone may choose to assert a definition with recourse to social institutions, cultural authorities, historical associations of words, personal values, common usage, and indeed, etymological origins. This is common in practice, but doesn't address the question of why the argument from etymology is a fallacy. It either ignores it or surreptitiously makes use of it.

4 is essentially anti-normative, which might seem like a good null hypothesis, but doesn't help us when we wish to assert the definition of a word.


I prefer operational definitions, in which a person in a certain context provides a definition for the duration of that context. But this doesn't escape the influence that etymology has on our definitional choices.
The etymological fallacy is often cited in Wikipedia talk pages in regards to disputes about terminology and article titles. An analysis of this concept could have ramifications.

"any word can mean anything if it is used that way" - precisely that, yes. Why do you call that a "paradox"? I'd probably say that's closer to demonstrated fact, considering how vastly meanings of words and language has changed across time and how other languages use entirely different words to describe things. But these points aren't mutually exclusive. We can intentionally decide upon a definition (#3) and then start using that way (#2), or refine usage with a definition, and this in turn informs norms of the future (#1??), which people can deviate from via #2 and/or #3.

Whatever psychological influence etymology has on our definitional choices, it is not normative and it should not be normative. Just as whatever influence  scientist's aesthetic preferences might have on hypotheses she comes up with should not be normative, what matters is testing their merits. When a word is in use by some community the norms of its use are fixed by communal convention. How it came to be used that way may be of historical interest, but it has no normative force. So we do not need a normative theory involving etymology and etymological fallacy is just a fallacy.

Regarding words meaning anything: As Humpty Dumpty said to Alice: "When I use a word, it means just what I choose it to mean... Who is to be master?"

The paradox of item 2 (any word can mean anything...) is moot, as there is a sort of Darwinian fitness in play: excessive ambiguity renders a word less useful (and a completely ambiguous word would be useless), and thus less used (arguably, there is a case for some ambiguity in human affairs, but that is another matter...)

This is like "normatively defining" what should be the effect of each diatonic chord on the piano. Words do not determine the message: it is the message that determines words.

The first job of definitions is to facilitate communication. To that end, words by default should have a meaning derived from current use. This is irrespective of their etymology; for clear communication, only current use matters.
Sometimes we need to communicate a specific concept for which no term in current use exists. Then, we need to use a stipulative definition. Stipulative definitions are made up, so again, you do not need to concern yourself with etymology. Although, etymology may be helpful when you are inventing a new word.
Sometimes we are trying to distill an existing term down to its essential nature. We may be trying to define "morality," for instance. For this we need to use an explicative definition. We start by taking common usage. Then we find something simple, systematic, and central about this common usage. Then we take this simple, systematic, central structure to be the whole meaning of the word, and argue that the word ought to be used in that way in the future, instead of the way it is currently used, because it leads to clearer thinking. At no point in this do we need to invoke etymology.
So there are several reasons to normatively define a word, none of which require etymology.
Words evolve in common usage, and can drift quite far from their etymological roots. Given that a definition's main job is to facilitate clear communication, and clear communication is beholden to current usage (and not etymological roots), etymology should for the most part be disregarded when we are defining words in philosophy.

@Barmar unfortunately, people who read texts from hundreds of years ago are often insufficiently aware of the changes in meaning that have occurred since the texts were written.

@phoog Forsooth!

@phoog By a symmetric argument, people who use a word only in a modern or colloquial sense are often insufficiently aware of the fact that they are using the word to mean something it did not natively mean.

@pygosceles I find that concept awfully terrific.

@R.M. let's not pretend that we understand and are understood as it is.

@R.M. you made me snort Dr. Pepper through my nose... well done.

As far as "refutation" of the etymological fallacy goes, you seem to be on the right track: there ought to be a recognizable, therefore applicable norm when inventing/coining words. You see this in science e.g. in medicine we might have words like "intracranial", decomposable into its components "intra" meaning inside and "cranium" meaning head/skull. This makes for easier learning of words because some of these words can be used elsewhere e.g. "intra" in "intraosseous" ("osseous" = bone) and "cranium" in "craniocaudal" ("cauadal" = behind/tail), you  get the idea. This automatically results in fewer words that need to be committed to memory and less-painful learning experience.
As you can see, building words from albeit arbitrary root words is a norm in scientific fields and maybe others, post-formalization, as well e.g. "prehistoric" ("pre" = before, "history" = you know), etc.
We also see such etymology-based definitions in ordinary vernacular e.g. "superyacht" and "hatemail" etc.
All in all, it's recommended that you use etymology-based definitions if you don't want a particular language to become extrahard to learn and use.

This is just one norm in science, though, and it's by no means universal. Still keeping in the field of medicine for examples, there's eponymous naming: In anatomy alone you've got Broca's area and Wernicke's area, fallopian tubes, the Golgi apparatus, and dozens more. There's structural naming: so many medications are named simply by shortening their IUPAC name, something that's useful for the biochemists but doesn't say anything about what they do. And how many diseases are named directly from the binomial name of the infectious agent, which is often arbitrarily chosen by its discoverer?

@Idran  that approach for naming drugs was already on the way out by the 1960s, and most drug names are now based on the INN scheme, which uses word stems based on mode of action rather than chemical composition. For example lisinopril, captopril and ramipril are all ACE inhibtors.

@Idran. that is correct I'm afraid.

@barbecue, thanks for the clarification.

Definitions and oughts aren't arguments. They can be useless definitions and wicked oughts, but they can't be fallacious arguments. If nothing was claimed to follow, nothing was claimed which does not follow. And if what is claimed really does follow from a wicked ought or a useless definition, then it really does follow. You cannot refute the argument if it is a syllogism or if there is no argument at all.
Contrast:
A: "Words should mean what they meant in 100 years ago. In 1924, gay meant happy. Bob and his male lover Steve are sad. Therefore you should not say that Bob and Steve are gay."
B: "Words should mean what they used to mean. Gay used to mean happy. Etc, Therefore etc."
In the B case, there may be an omitted premise: "the previous meaning was always the meaning ever previously". If included, the argument becomes a syllogism (still not a fallacy) but it is vulnerable to the falsification of this new premise. If omitted, the argument is vulnerable to a reductio, e.g. that we should mean "yes" as well as "happy", since the closest Anglo-Saxon word, gæ, has that meaning.
On the other hand, if the interlocutor retreats to A, then we can only dispute the premise ("why should words mean what they meant 100 years ago?"), agree to disagree and try to get along, or resolve the issue with sabers at dawn.

If the etymological fallacy is true, then no arguments are possible with words as there is no 'a priori' or axioms with regard to our words (except as used, or be defined, historically).  This would be self-contradictory.  Hence the notion is meaningless or false.
Take your pick.
